# Reseting Led to LOW form visual studio to arduino

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, arduino

i want to be able to turn the red led with the button from the arduino and being able to reset it with reset button in visual studio. The problem is it either go on and its not able to turn of from the reset button or it turns off and it is not able to turn on again if the program is not restarted.I would apriceate all the help.

the arduino code for the LED.

```
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      pinMode(BUTTON_SWITCH, INPUT_PULLUP);
      pinMode(BUTTON_ALARM, INPUT_PULLUP);
      pinMode(RED_LED, OUTPUT);

    }

if (digitalRead(BUTTON_ALARM) == LOW) {
    displayAlarm();
  }

   void displayAlarm() {
  digitalWrite(RED_LED, HIGH);
  tone(BUZZER, 1500, 700);
    if (Serial.available()) {
        // Read entire buffer up to newline character
        // Since on the C# side, serialPort1.WriteLine appends a newline character
        String respond = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
        if (respond == "RESET") {
            digitalWrite(RED_LED, LOW);
            digitalWrite(BUZZER, LOW);
        }
    }
```

The visual studio code in the reset button.

```
 private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            serialPort1.WriteLine("RESET");


    }
```

Comment: Side note: The Arduino code is C++, not C and the VS code is C#. You should adjust your tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a `float` variable `respond`. This is a numeric value and not a string but "RESET" is a string and you can't really compare a number to a string. You need to make `respond` a `String` and read the entire line with [`readStringUntil()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readstringuntil/):

```cpp
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(BUTTON_SWITCH, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(BUTTON_ALARM, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(RED_LED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    // If BUTTON_ALARM pressed, enable alarm
    if (digitalRead(BUTTON_ALARM) == LOW) {
        displayAlarm();
    }

    // Check if there is data in the serial port input buffer
    // If there is and it is "RESET", disable the alarm
    if (Serial.available()) {
        // Read entire buffer up to newline character
        // Since on the C# side, serialPort1.WriteLine appends a newline character
        String respond =Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
        if (respond == "RESET") {
            digitalWrite(RED_LED, LOW);
            digitalWrite(BUZZER, LOW);
        }
    }
}

void displayAlarm()
{
    digitalWrite(RED_LED, HIGH);
    tone(BUZZER, 1500, 700);
}
```

By default, `WriteLine` appends a newline. Make sure you haven't modified that. See: [SerialPort.NewLine Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.newline?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Ports_SerialPort_NewLine)

Comment: String respond = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');  Added this line of code but its still not working can't turn off the red led with the reset button on the windows form.

Comment: @gmatinski The way you have the brackets `{ }`, the code will only attempt to read from the serial port when `if (digitalRead(BUTTON_ALARM) == LOW) {` is true. Is that what you want? I have updated my answer with what I think you want.

Comment: I want to press the button once the alarm goes on buzzer and red led and when i press the reset button in the form app both of them to go off. I will edit the question.

Comment: This is what i have now in the arduino app down from the void loop but when i press the reset button the led still dont go off.

Comment: @gmatinski Your edit has removed the `loop()` function. But I think you still have the same problem. It will only check the serial port while the button is pressed. See my updated answer.

Comment: does this command  String respond = serialPort1.readStringUntil('\n'); goes in the arduino or the C# part because there is no such command in the arduino as serialPort1.

Comment: I havent put the void loop in the edit because its not needed for this matter.But i tried with the line that u send with the readStringUntil('\n'); but the reset button is still not reseting the led i dont know why.

Comment: @gmatinski Sorry, my mistake. That should be `Serial.readStringUntil('\n');`.

Comment: Actually the problem wasn't with this there isn't a single line of code that reads from arduino to c# i put this Serial.println("Alarm"); then ReadLine cmnd in c# and it worked.Anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: @gmatinski Huh? That's the complete opposite of what your post is asking about. Oh, well.....